# formulario de contato com Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

preciso criar um formulário de contato simples com laravel 5.1, no entanto, como sou mais de front-end, gostaria de alguma ideia do que posso fazer para criar esse formulário, alguns sites até explicam como se faz, mas não é com a versão atual do laravel, alguns pacotes do packagist geram um formulário mas também não explicam com clareza como usá-los.

alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: É uma questão bastante ampla. Você precisa nos dizer se ao menos você já o tem instalado e se está rodando.

Comment: O Formulário é um HTML basicamente, nada mais, nada menos.

Comment: A partir do laravel 5 o Form foi removido por padrão do framework você pode usar html normalmente, ou instalar segue o link explicando melhor [Forms & HTML](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html). :)

Answer (score 1):

Para conseguir isto e muito simples

Layout:

```
{{ Form:: open(array('action' => 'ContactController@getContactUsForm')) }} 

<ul class="errors">
@foreach($errors->all('<li>:message</li>') as $message)

@endforeach
</ul>

<div class="form-group">
{{ Form:: textarea ('message', '', array('placeholder' => 'Message', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'message', 'rows' => '4' )) }}
</div>



</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
{{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
{{ Form:: close() }}
```

Addicionar a seguinte route

```
Route::post('contact_request','ContactController@getContactUsForm
```

E o seguinte controller

```
public function getContactUsForm(){

        //Get all the data and store it inside Store Variable
        $data = Input::all();

        //Validation rules
        $rules = array (
            //'first_name' => 'required', uncomment if you want to grab this field
            //'email' => 'required|email',  uncomment if you want to grab this field
            'message' => 'required|min:5'
        );

        //Validate data
        $validator = Validator::make ($data, $rules);

        //If everything is correct than run passes.
        if ($validator -> passes()){

           Mail::send('emails.feedback', $data, function($message) use ($data)
            {
                //$message->from($data['email'] , $data['first_name']); uncomment if using first name and email fields 
                $message->from('feedback@gmail.com', 'feedback contact form');
    //email 'To' field: cahnge this to emails that you want to be notified.                    
    $message->to('feedback@gmail.com', 'John')->cc('feedback@gmail.com')->subject('feedback form submit');

            });
            // Redirect to page
   return Redirect::route('home')
    ->with('message', 'Your message has been sent. Thank You!');


            //return View::make('contact');  
         }else{
   //return contact form with errors
            return Redirect::route('home')
             ->with('error', 'Feedback must contain more than 5 characters. Try Again.');

         }
     }
}
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/creating-a-contactfeedback-form-with-laravel?page=1

Comment: Além de erros de sintaxe (espaços após ` Form::`), seu código não irá funcionar na versão 5.1.